Flat File as a source and EDI formatted file as destination through ssis
I am given a flat file and need to convert that flat file into EDI formatted file through SSIS. Can someone help me with this how to proceed.

What EDI document?  X12 or EDIFACT?  Why do you have to use SSIS?  That's not a great tool for parsing/creating EDI.

HI @user11497433 , could you please clarify more on the question like
EDI formatted file and how you are using with dataflow .
